# Counting ways of scoring k points in n games with half-points for draws

Tags: code-golf, combinatorics

**If a game can result in a win, worth one point; a draw, worth half a point; or a loss, worth no points; how many ways are there of scoring `k` points in `n` games?**

Applicable scenarios include NFL and chess.

- Input is via stdin, and consists of `n` and `k` on separate lines.
- `n` will be a non-negative integer. `(n ≤ 16)`
- `k` will be either a non-negative integer or a non-negative integer plus a half. `(k ≤ n)`
- Output is to stdout. It may, but does not have to, include a trailing newline.

#### Test cases

In each case, the first two lines are user-supplied input and the third line is the program output.

```
10
4.5
8350

16
8
5196627

16
13.5
13328

12
12
1
```

Comment: http://oeis.org/A027907

Comment: This is very insightful.  I have a working solution in c# which compiles to the requirements outlined within the problem.  I'm merely curious if someone can come up with a more compact solution than what I have.  Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

### Perl 59 bytes

```
@0=map"$v"+($v=$u)+($u=$_),@0,0,0for(@0=1)x<>;print@0[<>*2]
```

Iteratively generates each row of the triangle of trinomial coefficients up to *n*, and then prints the correct term, *2k*.

---

### Ruby 73 bytes

```
r=*1
gets.to_i.times{r<<0<<u=v=0;r.map!{|t|v+(v=u)+u=t}}
p r[gets.to_f*2]
```

Largely equivalent to the Perl solution above.

---

### Python 84 bytes

```
r=[1]
exec"r=map(sum,zip(r+[0],[0]+r,[0,0]+r))+[1];"*input()
print r[int(input()*2)]
```

Same method as both solutions above.

---

### PHP 91 bytes

```
<?for($n=+fgets(STDIN);(${$j--}+=$$j+${$j-1})?:$n--*$j=$i+=2;${0}=1);echo${fgets(STDIN)*2};
```

Despite being the longest, this was actually the most fun to work on.

Answer (score 3):

### R - 81

```
cat(sum(rowSums(do.call(expand.grid,replicate(scan(n=1),0:2,s=F)))==2*scan(n=1)))
```

A bit longer (106) but I also enjoyed writing it as a recursion:

```
Z=function(n,k)if(n<1|k<0)0 else if(n<2&k<3)1 else Z(n-1,k)+Z(n-1,k-1)+Z(n-1,k-2);Z(scan(n=1),2*scan(n=1))
```

Answer (score 3):

### C# (189 bytes)

Collaborative results from @glthomas, @recursive, @PeterTaylor and @primo

**Best Solution (189 Bytes)**
@glthomas and @recursive each found an additional 2 Bytes over the weekend. (We're convinced that this is the optimal solution using .Net 4.0 and compiling in VS 2010)!

```
using S=System.Console;class C{static void Main(){S.Write(G(G(),2*G()));}
static float G(float L=-1,float T=1){return L<0?float.Parse(S.ReadLine())
:T==0?1:--L<0?0:G(L,T)+G(L,T-1)+G(L,T-2);}}
```

**Improved Solution (193 Bytes)**

```
using System;class C{static void Main(){Func<float,float,float>W=null;W=(n,k)=>n<0?
k*float.Parse(Console.ReadLine()):k==0?1:--n<0?0:W(n,k)+W(n,k-1)+W(n,k-2);
Console.Write(W(W(-1,1),W(-1,2)));}}
```

The additional Byte was saved by combining the input acquisition and static recursive method into a single multipurpose `Func<>`.  Input acquisition is triggered when we pass in a negative value of `n`

**Original Solution (<strike>195</strike>, 194)**

```
using K=System.Console;class C{static void Main(){K.Write(T(int.Parse(K.ReadLine
()),2*float.Parse(K.ReadLine())));}static float T(int n,float k){return k==1?1:--
n<0?0:T(n,k)+T(n,k-1)+T(n,k-2);}}
```

Comment: You can save one more byte by changing `k<1?k+1` to `k==0?1`. It might be possible to save another if `--n` could somehow be moved to the front of the expression, i.e. `return--n...`

Comment: @primo, unfortunately that alters the output, because k can sometimes be -1 because of the T(n,k-2) method call.  Therefore we must check for k<1.

Comment: I don't think it will. The `k<0`s will be allowed to propagate, true, but they will eventually be quenched when `n` reaches zero. Because a `k` that is less than zero cannot produce a `k` equal to zero in the successive calls, it cannot change the result.

Comment: @primo I was incorporating both your second suggestion along with your first suggestion.  The idea to  `return--n..` was interfering with my testing.  I agree you can save a byte by converting `k<1?k+1` to `k==0?1`.  It appears the reason it doesn't work to move `--n` to the front of the expression is due to order of operation.  The condition on `k` takes precedent over the condition on `n`.  Wait until you see my post on 193 bytes :)

Comment: Nice. Here's 7 bytes more: `Func<float,float,float>W=null;W=(n,k)` => `Func<float,float,float>W=(n,k)`.

Comment: Nice trick with the null. I tried to use a recursive delegate and it didn't compile, so I dropped that line of investigation.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Interesting... mono-2.6.7 has no problems, although I see now that VS2010 chokes on it.

Comment: @primo check it out, 189 Bytes :)

Comment: @glthomas nice improvements!

Answer (score 1):

### C# (<strike>210</strike> 209 chars)

More efficient: iterative approach (209 chars):

```
using K=System.Console;class C{static void Main(){int
n=int.Parse(K.ReadLine()),k=(int)(2*float.Parse(K.ReadLine())),j;var t=new
int[k+3];for(t[2]=1;n-->0;)for(j=k+2;j>1;)t[j]+=t[--j]+t[j-1];K.Write(t[k+2]);}}
```

Less efficient: recursive approach (210 chars);

```
using K=System.Console;class C{static void Main(){int
n=int.Parse(K.ReadLine()),k=(int)(2*float.Parse(K.ReadLine()));K.Write(T(n,k));}static
int T(int n,int k){return k<1?k+1:--n<0?0:T(n,k)+T(n,k-1)+T(n,k-2);}}
```

Note that if `k` is non-integral, it should be supplied in a format applicable to the locale. In my case that means that I have to format the input using `,` as the decimal separator.

Comment: 209 Bytes, you missed an easy 4 bytes :)


using K=System.Console;class C{static void Main(){int n=int.Parse(K.ReadLine()),k=(int)(2*float.Parse(K.ReadLine())),j;var t=new int[k+3];for(t[2]=1;n-->0;)for(j=k+2;j>1;)t[j]+=t[--j]+t[j-1];K.Write(t[k+2]);}}

Comment: @user1177611, it wasn't clear that that was permitted. I've edited the question and, among other changes, made that explicit.

Comment: An anonymous user suggested saving a character in the iterative version by defining `t=new int[99]`. Technically with the current spec one could get away with `t=new int[35]`, but I think that limiting the value of `n` to no more than 16 is a pointless restriction.

Comment: Prior to being reworded, this problem started as an NFL win total combinatorics question. As such, 16 is currently the highest Win Total a team can achieve over one season.  Though there has been a lot of debate regarding the expansion to an 18 game season. So, t=new int[99] is virtually future proof (at least as it pertains to the NFL)

Answer (score 1):

### GolfScript (39 chars)

```
'.'/(~2*@,+[1]@{[0.@0+{@2$2$++@@}/+]}*=
```

[Online demo](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=OycxMAo0LjUnCgonLicvKH4yKkAsK1sxXUB7WzAuQDAre0AyJDIkKytAQH0vK119Kj0%3D)

Based on my [answer](/a/3822/194) to a [previous question](/q/3815/194) about *binomial* coefficients.

Answer (score 1):

### APL (22)

```
+/(2×⎕)=+⌿(N⍴3)⊤⍳3*N←⎕
```

It's not exactly efficient though (set your workspace size to a couple of gigabytes if you want it to actually work up to N=16).